# Pronunciation of English R

Tags: english, phonology, rhotics

I'm a native speaker and I notice I pronounce R as [ɹʋ] non finally, a spontaneous ɹ and ʋ. At the end of words though I use the regular ɹ. Is this normal and does anyone else do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is common. It is often broadly transcribed as [ɹʷ], using the "labialized/rounded" diacritic, but for me also the coarticulation is labiodental rather than bilabial. [Mechanical snail's answer to "Retroflex approximants in AE dialects" on ELU Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/94433/77227) uses the transcriptions [ɻᶹ] and [ψᶹ].

Comment: and in some British accents (notably Estruary English) the rounding is so extreme it's often broadly transcribed simply as [ʋ] with only the labial articulation transcribed and the tongue involvement ignored

Comment: American English rhotic /r/ is rounded. That shows up in a number of ways with different speakers and different contexts. That's also why Americans often hear, or pronounce (or occasionally spell) _Goethe_ as ['ɡɝtə]. The German /ö/, a mid front rounded vowel, that doesn't exist in English, is perceived as having an /r/ because it's rounded and in the same mouth space as /r/.

Comment: And non-rhotic BrE speakers also make the first syllables of Goethe and Girton the same. The roundedness is not perceived or duplicated, merely the centrality.